# Incorrect reputation calculated

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, reputation-graph

When I view my reputation points in my profile it seems that only the histogram is correct. However, the reputation score is stuck on 377, while actual the reputation points is 477 (it also shows an incorrect "next privilege" progress):

[image: Printscreen]

I also tried to see the page without login, and it shows the same. This bug appeared about two months ago, and I could not fix it.

Reputation points are the same (377) for months. At first I thought that some kind of cache needs to be refreshed, but it looks like this is not the case.

Comment: Seems the _-120_ on March 26 is missing from the histogram? The correct rep should be at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation if that helps figuring out which one is wrong.

Comment: @ivarni It also says 377.. hm, I will take a look into details...

Comment: Like I said on MSE, it's more useful to ask in your question whether there are any spam/offensive deleted posts on your profile (or, like Martijn pointed out, any invalidated bounty awards). Just reporting this a bug isn't very useful if it's one of those two, that's why I said you could ask about deleted posts/bounties on the meta of the site it was on...

Comment: It is so confusing because the rep score and the graph are saying different  reputation. Thats why I reported it here

Comment: Are you sure your reputation is 477 and not actually 377? Maybe you are thinking you got an association bonus on this site? IIRC you only get them on other sites.

Comment: The 100 missing reps matches the bounty from 19th of march which isn't on your answer anymore. It maybe got revoked, but that isn't included in the reputation graph.

Answer (score 8):

The reputation graph isn’t updated when a bounty is revoked. A 100 point bounty was revoked earlier this year, and that’s the difference you see here.

Bounties are revoked in very specific situations only, and I can’t go into detail why this one was revoked.

Comment: Is this a bug or is it intentional?

Comment: It’s a bug. Bounty invalidations have several related issues, this is one of them. I’d not worry much about it, and we generally strongly  encourage avoiding the set of circumstances that lead to such invalidations anyway.